# Arduino PyFirmata: WriteFile failed (PermissionError(13, 'Access is denied.', None, 5)) only when servo motor is connected

Tags: python, arduino, servo, pyfirmata

I have no idea why this is happening but I'll try to explain it as best I can, also sorry if this is a question that's been asked before, I looked around but couldn't really find anything related to what my issue is.

Essentially, I have a simple python program that is supposed to control a servo motor. I'm using pyfirmata for this. Whenever I try to move the servo, though, I get the error `serial.serialutil.SerialException: WriteFile failed (PermissionError(13, 'Access is denied.', None, 5))`. I've had this is in the past and known its been an issue where the port is already in use, however unplugging the servo motor immediately gets rid of this error. I also hear the windows USB disconnect sound, but I'm not sure if that's relevant.

In short, I get a permission error when my servo motor is plugged in and connected, but if I remove the wire at the D6 pin or remove the VCC pin from the servo motor I get no error. Any thoughts on what's causing this?

This is some example code I tried that still resulted in the error. I've also already tried using a different servo with no luck.

```
import time
from pyfirmata import Arduino, SERVO

PORT = "COM10"
servoPin = 6

try:
    board = Arduino(PORT)
except:
    print("Arduino board not plugged in! (Or not accessible on specified port)")
    time.sleep(5)
    quit()

board.digital[servoPin].mode = SERVO

for i in range (0, 180, 8):
    board.digital[servoPin].write(i)
    time.sleep(0.1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, got it working, this is still so weird.

I just bought and tried a different Arduino Nano and everything worked perfectly for whatever reason. The original Nano still works perfectly as long as its not being used with a servo? I have no clue why.

Anyways, if you have this issue, just switch out your Arduino board and everything should work.